# Getting periodic stats from ARDB with rocksDB as backend

Tags: monitoring, rocksdb

Is there a similar command in **ardb** like `stats` in **memcached** which gives the number of cumulative `get`, `set` ops separately as well as other stats such as `misses`?

e.g. in memcached I can do `stats` command and it gives:

```
STAT pid 1905
STAT uptime 87713
STAT time 1469108527
STAT version 1.4.25
STAT libevent 2.0.21-stable
STAT pointer_size 64
STAT rusage_user 300.101330
STAT rusage_system 711.654138
STAT curr_connections 18
STAT total_connections 4698
STAT connection_structures 739
STAT reserved_fds 40
STAT cmd_get 75355568
STAT cmd_set 3296663
STAT cmd_flush 0
STAT cmd_touch 0
STAT get_hits 44369791
STAT get_misses 30985777
STAT delete_misses 0
STAT delete_hits 0
STAT incr_misses 0
STAT incr_hits 0
STAT decr_misses 0
STAT decr_hits 0
STAT cas_misses 0
STAT cas_hits 0
STAT cas_badval 0
STAT touch_hits 0
STAT touch_misses 0
STAT auth_cmds 0
STAT auth_errors 0
STAT bytes_read 3615072874
STAT bytes_written 16173356516
STAT limit_maxbytes 3670016000
STAT accepting_conns 1
STAT listen_disabled_num 0
STAT time_in_listen_disabled_us 0
STAT threads 8
STAT conn_yields 1763246
STAT hash_power_level 17
STAT hash_bytes 1048576
STAT hash_is_expanding 0
STAT malloc_fails 0
STAT bytes 331012787
STAT curr_items 176322
STAT total_items 3296663
STAT expired_unfetched 0
STAT evicted_unfetched 0
STAT evictions 0
STAT reclaimed 0
STAT crawler_reclaimed 0
STAT crawler_items_checked 0
STAT lrutail_reflocked 0
END
```

Using this I can find out the number of get operations in the last second (by subtracting using any client library in python). I want to get the number of get and set operations per second for `ardb` as well.

The only command that I have found is `info commandstats` and it gives:

```
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
info commandstats
$128
# Commandstats
cmdstat_get:calls=755061,usec=2009117846,usecpercall=2660
cmdstat_info:calls=23,usec=87805,usecpercall=3817
```

While this can give me `get` stats, there is nothing for `set` and `misses`. Is there anything like that in ardb or some hack which can get me this info? I am using rocksdb as backend and need something that be used for monitoring from python preferably.

**P.S** I am unable to create the `ardb` tag because of low rep, maybe someone else can create it?